# how to save prices in mysql

Tags: mysql, decimal

I have a number value fetched from an excel-sheet, e.g. 4,631.26.
I would like to save it in MySQL as Decimal(10,2). What I have done so far:

changed it from 4,631.26 to 4631.26 like this:

```
var s = myNumber;
myNumber = s.replace(',', '');

"INSERT INTO `articles` (preis) VALUES ("+myNumber+")"
```

It will be saved as Decimal and everything looks fine. But when I try to read it shows only the first Digit.

I changed Decimal(10,2) to double, but the problem remains.

Comment: when you try do read it are you doing so in php or mysql ( are you using a GUI (workbench, hedisql etc)) what is the data type of preis, how does it look from command line sql.

Comment: how are you reading it back? checking the format of your cell may be a good idea

Comment: I am using sequelPro and phpMyAdmin, the datatype is DECIMAL(10,2). it looks fine in my commandline: 4631.26

Comment: @bansi the format of the cell in Excel is number

Answer (score 0):

I think you can strip off all the dots and commas and multiply the number by 100 and save it to the database. Later you can retrieve the number and divide by 100 before returning back to front end.

1. So if number is 4,631.26 => 46312600 => Saved to MySql
2. While retrieving back in program => 46312600/100 = 463126 => Apply decimal before last two digits => 4631.26